# MS Access SQL: Your query does not include the specified expression....as part of an aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access, aggregate

I can't figure out why my query is giving me the error in the title. The exact error is:

> Your query does not include the specified expression ' `IIf([Standard_Shift_Rate]=0,0,Round([SumOfqty_complete]/((((Round([Uf_Shift_Standard]*[pcs_per_mch_hr],0))/[Uf_Shift_Standard])/60)*([actual_shift_length_minutes])),2))`' as part of an aggregate function

The intention for the field in question (`OEE_Shift`) is to return the value `170` (numeric) based on some criteria I have on the main form.

**The code:**

I intend to run all of the code below, but I've commented out what I think is not related to this problem. Nevertheless, it's there for you to look at if you think it will help solve this problem.

```
SELECT /*dbo_jobtran.job,
       dbo_jobtran.suffix,
       dbo_job.item,
       dbo_job.description,
       dbo_job.Uf_Production_Line,
       Sum(dbo_jobtran.qty_complete) AS SumOfqty_complete,
       dbo_jobtran.shift,
       IIf(Nz([Forms]![DTForm]![STCO])="",(Switch(Max([SL])="8",(Switch((Time()>=#12/30/1899 6:0:0# And Time()<#12/30/1899 14:0:0#),DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 6:0:0#,Time()),(Time()>=#12/30/1899 14:0:0# And Time()<#12/30/1899 22:0:0#),DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 14:0:0#,Time()),True,IIf((DateDiff("n",#10:00:00 PM#,Time())>0),DateDiff("n",#10:00:00 PM#,Time()),DateDiff("n",#10:00:00 PM#,Time()+1)))),Max([SL])="10",(Switch((Time()>=#12/30/1899 5:0:0# And Time()<#12/30/1899 15:0:0#),DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 5:0:0#,Time()),True,DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 15:0:0#,Time()))),Max([SL])="12",(Switch((Time()>=#12/30/1899 3:0:0# And Time()<#12/30/1899 15:0:0#),DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 3:0:0#,Time()),True,DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 15:0:0#,Time()))),1=1,(Switch((Time()>=#12/30/1899 6:0:0# And Time()<#12/30/1899 14:0:0#),DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 6:0:0#,Time()),(Time()>=#12/30/1899 14:0:0# And Time()<#12/30/1899 22:0:0#),DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 14:0:0#,Time()),True,DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 22:0:0#,Time()))))),(DateDiff("n",[Forms]![DTForm]![STCO],Time()))) AS Mins_since_start, Sum(Round(([Uf_Pieces_Per_Labor_Hour_Bonus]/60*[charfld3]),2)) AS Rate_per_min_cons_units, dbo_jobtran.trans_date, [Uf_Standard_Crew_Size]*[Uf_Budgeted_Pieces_Per_Labor_Hr] AS Budgeted_CN_Per_Hr, dbo_item.charfld3, dbo_jrt_sch.Uf_Standard_Crew_Size, dbo_jrt_sch.Uf_Budgeted_Pieces_Per_Labor_Hr, Round(((([Uf_Standard_Crew_Size]*[Uf_Budgeted_Pieces_Per_Labor_Hr]*8*[charfld3])/7.5)/60),0) AS Budgeted_Machine_Rate_Per_Minute, Round((([Budgeted_CN_Per_Hr]*[Mins_since_start])/60),2) AS RT_EXP_BN, Round((Sum([dbo_jobtran]![qty_complete])*[charfld3])/[Mins_since_start],2) AS RT_ACT_M_Rate, Sum([dbo_jobtran]![qty_complete])-[RT_EXP_BN] AS Diff_Budget_Rate, IIf([RT_EXP_BN]=0,0,Round(((Sum([dbo_jobtran]![qty_complete])/[RT_EXP_BN])),2)) AS OEE, Round((Sum([dbo_jobtran]![qty_complete])/[Mins_since_start])*480,0) AS Projected_Num, [RT_ACT_M_Rate]-[Budgeted_Machine_Rate_Per_Minute] AS Diff_Budgeted_MacRate, dbo_job.whse, Round((Sum([dbo_jobtran]![qty_complete])/([Forms]![DTForm]![Text4]*[Mins_since_start])*60),2) AS ACT_PPLHR, Round((Sum([dbo_jobtran]![qty_complete])/([Forms]![DTForm]![Text4]*[Mins_since_start])*60),2)-[Uf_Budgeted_Pieces_Per_Labor_Hr] AS Diff_Budget_PPLHR, IIf(Nz(Forms!DTForm![STCO])="","Null field","Unknown") AS Expr1, DateDiff("n",Forms!DTForm![STCO],Time()) AS Expr2, dbo_jrt_sch.Uf_Budgeted_Crew_Size, dbo_job.Uf_Shift_Standard AS SL,
       (
  Switch(

          Max([SL])="8",

            (Switch(

              (Time()>=#12/30/1899 6:0:0# And Time()<#12/30/1899 14:0:0#),
                #14:00:00#,
              (Time()>=#12/30/1899 14:0:0# And Time()<#12/30/1899 22:0:0#),
                #22:00:00#,
              True,
                #06:00:00#
            )),

          Max([SL])="10",

            (Switch(

              (Time()>=#12/30/1899 5:0:0# And Time()<#12/30/1899 15:0:0#),
                #15:00:00#,
              True,
                #01:00:00#
            )),

          Max([SL])="12",

            (Switch(

              (Time()>=#12/30/1899 3:0:0# And Time()<#12/30/1899 15:0:0#),
                #15:00:00#,
              True,
                #03:00:00#
            ))  
        )

        ) AS end_time,

    Nz([Forms]![DTForm]![STCO],

    (Switch(

      Max([SL])="8",

        (Switch(

          (Time()>=#12/30/1899 6:0:0# And Time()<#12/30/1899 14:0:0#),
            DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 6:0:0#,Time()),
          (Time()>=#12/30/1899 14:0:0# And Time()<#12/30/1899 22:0:0#),
            DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 14:0:0#,Time()),
          True,
            IIf((DateDiff("n",#10:00:00 PM#,Time())>0),
              DateDiff("n",#10:00:00 PM#,Time()),
              DateDiff("n",#10:00:00 PM#,Time()+1)))),  

      Max([SL])="10",

        (Switch(

          (Time()>=#12/30/1899 5:0:0# And Time()<#12/30/1899 15:0:0#),
            DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 5:0:0#,Time()),
          True,
            DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 15:0:0#,Time()))),

      Max([SL])="12",

        (Switch(

          (Time()>=#12/30/1899 3:0:0# And Time()<#12/30/1899 15:0:0#),
            DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 3:0:0#,Time()),
          True,
            DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 15:0:0#,Time()))),

      1=1,
        (Switch(
          (Time()>=#12/30/1899 6:0:0# And Time()<#12/30/1899 14:0:0#),
            DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 6:0:0#,Time()),
          (Time()>=#12/30/1899 14:0:0# And Time()<#12/30/1899 22:0:0#),
            DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 14:0:0#,Time()),
          True,
            DateDiff("n",#12/30/1899 22:0:0#,Time())))
    ))

    ) AS start_time,
    (DateDiff("n", [start_time], [end_time])) AS actual_shift_length_minutes,*/
    IIf([Standard_Shift_Rate]=0,0,Round([SumOfqty_complete]/((((Round([Uf_Shift_Standard]*[pcs_per_mch_hr],0))/[Uf_Shift_Standard])/60)*([actual_shift_length_minutes])),2)) AS OEE_Shift
FROM dbo_jrt_sch
INNER JOIN ((dbo_job
             INNER JOIN dbo_jobtran ON (dbo_job.job = dbo_jobtran.job)
             AND (dbo_job.suffix = dbo_jobtran.suffix))
            INNER JOIN dbo_item ON dbo_job.item = dbo_item.item) ON (dbo_jrt_sch.job = dbo_job.job)
AND (dbo_jrt_sch.suffix = dbo_job.suffix)
GROUP BY dbo_jobtran.job,
         dbo_jobtran.suffix,
         dbo_job.item,
         dbo_job.description,
         dbo_job.Uf_Production_Line,
         dbo_jobtran.shift,
         dbo_jobtran.trans_date,
         [Uf_Standard_Crew_Size]*[Uf_Budgeted_Pieces_Per_Labor_Hr],
         dbo_item.charfld3,
         dbo_jrt_sch.Uf_Standard_Crew_Size,
         dbo_jrt_sch.Uf_Budgeted_Pieces_Per_Labor_Hr,
         Round(((([Uf_Standard_Crew_Size]*[Uf_Budgeted_Pieces_Per_Labor_Hr]*8*[charfld3])/7.5)/60),0),
         dbo_job.whse,
         IIf(Nz(Forms!DTForm![STCO])="","Null field","Unknown"),
         DateDiff("n",Forms!DTForm![STCO],Time()),
         dbo_jrt_sch.Uf_Budgeted_Crew_Size,
         dbo_job.Uf_Shift_Standard,
         OEE_Shift
HAVING (((dbo_jobtran.job)=[Forms]![DTForm]![Text116])
        AND ((dbo_jobtran.suffix)=[Forms]![DTForm]![Text118])
        AND ((dbo_jobtran.shift)=[Forms]![DTForm]![Combo33])
        AND ((dbo_jobtran.trans_date)=[Forms]![DTForm]![Text29])
        AND ((dbo_jrt_sch.Uf_Budgeted_Pieces_Per_Labor_Hr) IS NOT NULL));
```

Comment: You need that expression included in the GROUP BY statement, I believe. Anything in the SELECT statement that isn't contained in an aggregate function needs to be included in the GROUP BY statement.

Comment: I tried that in 2 ways. First I put the expression definition in there - same error. Then I put it's alias (`OEE_Shift`) in there - again, the same error.

Comment: This is a tad bit more difficult because it's Access SQL, which has slight differences in syntax and stuff.

Comment: Yeah, Access SQL always throws me for a loop with all its subtle differences. Have you tried making this a subquery, giving all the expressions alias, and referring to them that way? You can't use alias in a GROUP BY statement within the same query, but you can refer to aliases in a subquery from a superquery.